# Text File edit using shell scripting in Linux

Tags: shell

I have a text file with a single line as given below. first case 1).How can I add symbol(#) at starting of that line and then in second case 2).How can I remove symbol(#) and change -o with -r and overwrite that file using shell script.

```
sed -i 's/^/#/;s/-o/-r/' file.txt         #this will add #(symbol) and replace o with r
sed -i 's/^#//'                           #this will remove #(symbol)
```

**Input file.txt**

```
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -o &
```

**expected output file.txt**:

```
#****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```

**Input file.txt**

```
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```

**expected output file.txt**:

```
#****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```

**Input file.txt**

```
#****root/var/con.d/wtdog -o &       #Pound symbol can be more than one at starting of line
```

**expected output file.txt**:

```
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```

**Input file.txt**

```
#####****root/var/con.d/wtdog -o &
```

**expected output file.txt**:

```
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```

My code supposed to give this kind of output file but in case of more than one #(symbol) it removes only one #(symbol)

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes, share what you have tried. But also consider using the "sed" command.

Comment: I added what I did.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed to do the edit in place (-i flag)

```
sed -i .bak 's/^/#/'  file.txt
```

to add a # 
and

```
sed -i .bak 's/^#//;s/ -o / -r /'  file.txt
```

to remove the leading # and replace -o with -r

note the -i option will edit the file in place and create a backup file.txt.bak with the previous contents

Comment: This give output in terminal but I need to overwrite that file instead of just displaying in terminal.And I also want to replace -o with -r

Comment: updated the answer to do the -o / -r.  the command should edit the file as noted in the answer

Comment: I tried this one but suppose if I have more than one pound at a starting of line this will remove only one pound symbol same as with removing pound symbol so I am looking for general solution

Comment: please clarify your question then - add a number of sample inputs and the expected output for each one

Answer (score -1):

To add a pound symbol you can read the line with `head` and `echo` it back to the file (caution: destroys any other content).

```
line=$(head -n 1 file.txt)
echo \#$line > file.txt
```

To perform your second operation, I used regex in `sed` and chopped off the first character with `:1`:

```
line=$(head -n 1 file.txt)
echo "${line:1}" | sed -e 's/ -o / -r /' > file.txt
```

Sample run:

```
$ cat file.txt
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -o &
$ ./a.sh
$ cat file.txt
#****root/var/con.d/wtdog -o &
$ ./b.sh
$ cat file.txt
****root/var/con.d/wtdog -r &
```